# Farm BackUp error

Tags: 2016, backup, server-farm, farm

Getting below error while performing back up on SP2016 OP farm.

> Object Crawl-0 (C: on ) failed in event OnBackupComplete.For more information, see the spbackup.log or sprestore.log file located in the backup directory.

Any Idea on how to resolve this?

Comment: Can you check the log files and see what's error there? The one you mentioned above could be a generic representation of error.

Comment: Yes that given insights, it's actually permissions issue and when given needed permission it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Backup-SPFarm command should use a network share where The service accounts, Farm accounts and SQL Server service accounts have Full Control access to the share. This is because SharePoint uses SQL commands for running parts of the backup and these execute in SQL Server's context.

More information:

http://www.adventuresinsharepoint.co.uk/2015/01/11/sharepoint-2013-backup-fails-object-crawl-0-e-on-ww-sp-failed-in-event-onbackupcomplete/

http://amolmeshe.blogspot.in/2013/06/sharepoint-2013-farm-back-error-object.html

Comment: It is as given permission issues, and when it sorted out - worked .thank you.